# How to correctly SUM() in my query?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a this table containing order information for two orders (`orderID 1` and `orderID 2`):

```
┌--------------------------------------┐
| orderID | productID | amount | price |
├--------------------------------------┤
|       1 |         1 |      5 | 19.95 |
|       1 |         2 |      2 | 12.95 |
|       1 |         3 |   NULL |  3.49 |
|       1 |         4 |   NULL |  1.49 |
|       1 |         5 |   NULL |  0.99 |
|       2 |         1 |     11 | 19.95 |
|       2 |         2 |      4 | 12.95 |
|       2 |         3 |   NULL |  3.49 |
└--------------------------------------┘
```

Product IDs `1` and `2` are items, where the orderer can chose an arbitrary amount of items.

All products with IDs greater than `2` are upgrades to product ID `1`, thus the orderer cannot chose the amount but only chose it or not chose it.

Now I want to calculate the final `SUM()` of each order.

The proper formula for the first order would be

```
  5 * 19.95
+ 2 * 12.95
+ 5 *  3.49
+ 5 *  1.49
+ 5 *  0.99
-----------
=    155.50
```

So I started to define my query like this:

```
SELECT
    `orderID`,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN `amount` IS NOT NULL
            THEN `amount` * `price`
            ELSE `price`
        END
    ) AS `total`
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `orderID`
```

But the problem is now that all the optional items (with `productID > 2`) are only counted once, but I need them as many times as `productID 1` is chosen. How can I access the `amount` of `productID 1` in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a self join. Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.OrderID, SUM(COALESCE(a.amount, b.amount) * a.price)
FROM orders a
INNER JOIN orders b
ON a.OrderID = b.OrderID
AND b.ProductID = 1
GROUP BY a.OrderID
```

Comment: I find it hard to comprehend why, but it works; thanks!

Comment: It joins the table against itself. Or orders (a) is each row while orders (b) is just the first product id for that order. Coalesce gives the first non null value so if a has an amount it uses that, but if not it uses the amount from b.

Comment: I just saw that this doesn't return rows where `product1 = NULL`. How can I fetch rows where `product1 = NULL` but `product2 > 0`? [I opened another question for this issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187299/how-to-correctly-sum-in-my-query-part-2)

Comment: Not sure using a LEFT OUTER JOIN will do it on its own. Depends if you want to cope with a situation where you had product id 2, 3 and 4, and wanted to use the quantity from 2 for 3 & 4 when they were null.